# In crystallography, how does the real space R factor relate to the atomic B factor?

Tags: crystallography

In assessing the quality of different parts of an atomic model derived from diffraction data, you can look at the real space R factor or at the atomic B factor. Do these give the same information or do they complement each other? In which scenarios would you look at one or the other or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the real space R factor, you need an atomic model plus the electron density map (e.g. 2Fo-Fc map) derived from the diffraction data and the model. You calculate the correlation of the expected density (derived from the model alone) and the 2Fo-Fc map for given areas in the model. For example, you could calculate a residue-wise real space R factor. The lower its value, the better the correlation. For macromolecular structures deposited in the protein data bank, residues with particularly poor correlation are listed in the validation report (see [user guide section 6.1](https://www.wwpdb.org/validation/2017/XrayValidationReportHelp#fit_protein_na_chains)).

The B factors (also called atomic displacement parameters or temperature factors) are part of the atomic model. They get optimized during refinement to obtain the best fit between measured and calculated diffraction data. If the model is accurate, the B factors reflect the disorder of each atom. If there are glaring errors in the model (either misplacement of atoms, or spurious atoms in the model that are not really in the structure), refinement will inflate the B factors of these atoms (this de-emphasises the contributions of these atoms to the calculated diffraction data).

> [...] how does the real space R factor relate to the atomic B factor?

Both measures give local information about the quality of the structure. B factors are easily obtainable (they are deposited with the coordinates of a structure) whereas the real space R factor requires a calculation using suitable software.

> Do these give the same information or do they complement each other?

When the real space R factor is high in a given region, it means the atomic model is bad at representing the structure in this region.

When the B factor is high, it can mean one of two things.

1. The region is correctly modelled and has a high degree of disorder (the real space R factor would be low, showing adequate interpretation).
2. There are spurios atoms in the model. The B factor will be inflated during refinement as a way of "downplaying" this problem (the real space R factor would be low as well).

When you find a couple of high B factors in a region of otherwise low B factors, you can be pretty sure there is a problem with the model that could be fixed. In that case, it is time to look at the electron density.

> In which scenarios would you look at one or the other or both?

The real space R factor suffers from bias because it compares something calculated from the model with something calculated from the model and the diffraction data (for 2Fo-Fc maps). If you are looking at cryo-EM densities, though, or any other technique where the map does not rely on the model, there is no bias.

The B factor is provided by the crystallographers who solved the structure, so you don't exactly know what they did during refinement to arrive at the B factors.

If you are looking at a structure you are not familiar, a quick look at B factors can tell you which regions were easy to model and which were tricky. Graphing the B factors or color-coding a 3D visualization by B factors might give you an idea of problems in building the atomic model.

One the other hand, a quick look at the real space R factor can tell you which parts of the structure are represented well by the atomic model and which are not. It is a bit easier to interpret, but much harder to obtain unless you have the computational infrastructure already set up.

Once you find red flags using either method, it makes sense to look at the electron density and the model on a 3D display to see what might be going on.